# Переключение тем(dark mode) в SPA VUE на SCSS

Tags: css, bootstrap, vue.js, scss, bootstrap-vue

Хочу реализовать переключение тем в веб-приложении на vue. Я использую бустрап и тему с сайта bootswatch.com. Тема оттуда представляет собой просто scss-файл с переменными. Именно поэтому мне не подходит способ, который широко предлагают в интернете, типа такого:

```
body {
  color: black;
}
body[data-theme="dark"] {
  color: white
}
```

Я пытаюсь придумать какой-то вариант динамически переключать подключение scss файл, но мне кажется это невозможно.
Никаких статей по динамической темизации я не нашел.
Вопрос: как динамически переключать bootstrap тему в vue-приложении?

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю поможет ли мой ответ.

У меня в проекте была задача сделать 2 темы для 1 приложения.

1. Все переменные, которые должны измениться были вынесены в отдельный файл colors.scss.
2. В webpack-е было настроено подключение одного или другого такого файла в зависимости от билда: 1 или 2 проект.
3. Была создана папка themes. В index файле сначала подключаются цвета, затем подключается основной main.scss, который использует эти переменные.

Во всех местах где используются цвета - нужно поставить переменные.

Не делал темные темы, но похоже, что нужно менять цвет bg, основной цвет текста и задать main-color, который будет белым или черным соответственно использоваться для всех элементов.

https://monosnap.com/file/Oa7gmeyl1tldnGyb2m2Gqja4LShvfk

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но это и так уже есть. Вы предлагаете вариант, в котором для смены темы на заново билдить проект. А я имел ввиду дать пользователю возможность выбора темы.

Comment: Понял о чем Вы. Но похоже, что вам так же нужны 2 сборки css, чтобы не хранить все стили - тк все происходит на стадии сборки webpack. Есть несколько вариантов.
1. Тянуть необходимый css для стилизации в зависимости от выбранных настроек.
2. Подключать 2 css сразу и менять глобальный класс у body.

Как-то пользовался приложение nylas mail. Там были разные темы.
Это на electron-е.

Можно заглянуть в их исходники на github - https://github.com/nylas/nylas-mail.